# how to copy all text from a certain webpage and save it to notepad C#

Tags: c#, winforms, copy, notepad

I have a C# Windows Forms app that launches a webpage based on some criteria.

Now I would like my app to automatically copy all the text from that page (which is in CSV format) and paste and save it in notepad.

Here is a link to an example of the data that needs to be copied:
http://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/FAJS/2012/10/28/DailyHistory.html?req_city=Johannesburg&req_state=&req_statename=South+Africa&format=1

Any Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhd1f0sw.aspx combined with http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/21720-Writing-string-content-file.aspx

```
public static void DownloadString ()
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    string reply = client.DownloadString("http://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/FAJS/2012/10/28/DailyHistory.html?req_city=Johannesburg&req_state=&req_statename=South+Africa&format=1");

    StringBuilder stringData = new StringBuilder();
    stringData = reply;  
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\Temp\tmp.txt", FileMode.Create);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[stringData.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < stringData.Length; i++)
    {
        buffer[i] = (byte)stringData[i];
    }
    fs.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    fs.Close();
}
```

**Edit** Adil uses the `WriteAllText` method, which is even better. So you will get something like this:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string reply = client.DownloadString("http://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/FAJS/2012/10/28/DailyHistory.html?req_city=Johannesburg&req_state=&req_statename=South+Africa&format=1");
System.IO.File.WriteAllText (@"C:\Temp\tmp.txt", reply);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is actually the most easiest and quickest way. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can use the new toy [HttpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx) from .NET 4.5, example how to get google page:

```
 var httpClient = new HttpClient();
 File.WriteAllText("C:\\google.txt",    
                           httpClient.GetStringAsync("http://www.google.com")
                                     .Result);
```

Comment: @Mr_Green: yes, still work, but you need to install lib which contain HttpClient from nuget

Answer (score 3):

Simple way: use [`WebClient.DownloadFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadfile.aspx) and save as a `.txt` file:

```
var webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.DownloadFile("http://www.google.com",@"c:\google.txt");
```

Answer (score 1):

You need [**WebRequest**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx) to read the stream of and save to string to text file. You can use [**File.WriteAllText**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealltext.aspx) to write it to file.

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create ("http://www.contoso.com/default.html");
                    request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;            
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse ();            
Console.WriteLine (response.StatusDescription);            
Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream ();            
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (dataStream);            
string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd ();
System.IO.File.WriteAllText (@"D:\path.txt", responseFromServer );
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use a webclient to do this:

```
System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
byte[] raw = wc.DownloadData("http://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/FAJS/2012/10/28/DailyHistory.html?req_city=Johannesburg&req_state=&req_statename=South+Africa&format=1");

string webData = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(raw);
```

then the string **webData** contains the complete text of the webpage

Comment: You can also use the `DownloadString` method

Comment: I think StringBuilder is preferred because of large data? just asking I am new.

Comment: ok got it thank you.. I was thinking in different way @JPHellemons